# How to implement FTS in android using room?

Tags: android, android-room

I need to perform search operations in my app so I have tried to implement a Full-text search using a room in android. But I'm not getting the desired output.The query is not clear to me. I have mentioned the query below:

```
  @Query("SELECT posts.postId,posts.authorName,posts.authorImageUrl,posts.title,posts.message,posts.thumbnailUrl,posts.downloadUrl,posts.postTimeStamp,posts.type,posts.seenByUser,posts.mimeType,posts.isBookmarked FROM postsFts JOIN posts ON (posts.postId = postsFts.postId)")
fun searchInPostsLocalDB(query: String): List<PostsModel>
```

I want to get lists of matching rows in output.

Comment: Do you want the whole `Post` object [in List]?

Comment: yes, list of objects where query matches in row.

Comment: Share the name of your FTS Table.

Comment: postsFts is the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `match` which checks which row is matching with the query. So the answer is:

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM postsFts JOIN posts ON (posts.postId = postsFts.postId) WHERE postsFts MATCH :query")
fun searchInPostsLocalDB(query: String): List<PostsModel>
```

And use `*` to surround the `query` to make it a wildcard.

For example : `*tarun*`